# A question about the proof that a polynomial is solvable by radicals iff Galois group is solvable (Theorem 14.7.39 of Dummit and Foote)

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation, galois-theory, solvable-groups

My question is about the following theorem:

> A polynomial $f(x)$ can be solved by radicals if and only if its Galois group is solvable.

The difficulty arises in the last assertion in this paragraph:

> Suppose first that $f(x)$ can be solved by radicals. Then each root of $f(x)$ is contained in an extension as in the lemma [each root is contained in a root extension $K$ that is Galois over $F$ and each extension $K_{i+1}/K_i$ is cyclic] The composite $L$ of such extensions is again of the same type. Let $G_i$ be the subgroups corresponding to the subfields of $K_i$. Since $Gal(K_{i+1}/K_i) = G_i/G_{i+1}$, it follows that the Galois group $G = Gal(L/F)$ is solvable.

My difficulty in understanding comes at the last assertion, that $G$ is solvable. For some reason I am unable to see why that should be true. Any help in clarifying this would be appreciated.

Comment: An extension of a cyclic (and hence solvable) group and a solvable group is solvable. See also the related questions at the right margin.

Comment: Ah, OK that clears things up. Thanks for the help.